# set a timeout for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, settimeout

I am given a issue where a timeout is getting occured on the qa environment. This is the exact issue.
**JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back(maybe due to timeout)**

I want to replicate the same in my local machine. Fir that reason what i am doing is setting the key called "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" as "5000" in my  application.properties. i am expecting a timeout to happen in 5 sec. to verify whther the key is set or not i am printing the key as

System.out.println(envVariable.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));

The above print statement is giving me the value 5000.  My actual code looks something like this

```
 ...
try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
```

i am mking my code to sleep for 6 sec. now i can expect the system to go in timeout right? the system should give some issue telling timeout occured but the flow is continued as normal. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the snippet that you have shared it seems you are using Hibernate. It internally uses Hikari for connection mechanism. Hence it will be good if we try to change the default connection timeout and other related properties as required so as to tweak the local setup.

Here are few of the examples:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

For more details and the default values please refer to Hikari's GitHub page.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby